# Need the correct regexp expression for breaking down URL

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am looking to break this kind of data further - instead of the URL part, I want more details like department, category, product etc if available.

This is from Cloudera's tutorial

Text to decode:

```
150.47.54.136 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:14 -0400] "GET /department/fan%20shop/category/water%20sports/product/Pelican%20Sunstream%20100%20Kayak/add_to_cart HTTP/1.1" 200 1932 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

Cloudera tutorial command to execute in HIVE Query Editor App in Hue

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE intermediate_access_logs (
    ip STRING,
    date STRING,
    method STRING,
    url STRING,
    http_version STRING,
    code1 STRING,
    code2 STRING,
    dash STRING,
    user_agent STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'input.regex' = '([^ ]*) - - \\[([^\\]]*)\\] "([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*)" (\\d*) (\\d*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"',
    'output.format.string' = "%1$$s %2$$s %3$$s %4$$s %5$$s %6$$s %7$$s %8$$s %9$$s")
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/original_access_logs';
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Assuming the language supports lookaheads I'd use a regex that does the following:

- Find the `"Get` string
- Move through the `get` string and parse its text.
- Assuming the section name and value sets are all `/` delimited, we'll look for the `category`, `product`, and `department` key names and return the associated values
- Allow the key names to appear in any order
- The regex should be somewhat modular to allow adding and removing additional key/value sets on demand

**The Regex**

```
^.*?"GET\s+(?=[^"]*?/category/([^"/]*)[/\s])(?=[^"]*?/product/([^"/]*)[/\s])(?=[^"]*?/department/([^"/]*)[/\s])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: to see the image better, right click the image and select open in new window or new tab.

**Capture Groups**

- capture group 0 will have a fragment of the entire source string
- capture group 1 will have the `category` value
- capture group 2 will have the `product` value
- capture group 3 will have the `department` value

**Sample Matches**
Given your sample text:

> [14/Jun/2014:10:30:14 -0400] "GET /department/fan%20shop/category/water%20sports/product/Pelican%20Sunstream%20100%20Kayak/add_to_cart HTTP/1.1" 200 1932 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"

```
[0] = 150.47.54.136 - - [14/Jun/2014:10:30:14 -0400] "GET 
[1] = water%20sports
[2] = Pelican%20Sunstream%20100%20Kayak
[3] = fan%20shop
```

## Explanation

Generally speaking the regex will move the cursor forward until it finds the `"get` string, from there it uses positive lookaheads to collect the various values. These lookaheads can be duplicated to collect additional chunks of substrings as needed.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "GET                     '"GET'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /category/               '/category/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"/]*                   any character except: '"', '/' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [/\s]                    any character of: '/', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /product/                '/product/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"/]*                   any character except: '"', '/' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [/\s]                    any character of: '/', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /department/             '/department/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"/]*                   any character except: '"', '/' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [/\s]                    any character of: '/', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```